# write character for whitespace

Tags: python

need some help  to solve my problem.

```
import re

txt = "range 123.123.123.123 123.123.123.123"

x = re.search(r'^range \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$',txt)

print(x)

if x:
  print("match")
else:
  print("No match")
```

i want this result:

```
set type iprange start-ip 123.123.123.123 end-ip 123.123.123.123
```

i guess its not that difficult to replace "range" to "set type iprange start-ip" but how do i write a character in a whitespace?

Answer (score 3):

How about?

```
 _, start_ip, end_ip = txt.split()
result = f"set type iprange start-ip {start_ip} end-ip {end_ip}"
```

Strings are immutable and hence an existing string cannot be modified. However, you can create a new string by first splitting your original string by space and then using f-strings to fill in the placeholders.
This assumes that your original string is delimited by whitespaces.

There are [multiple ways](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to format strings in Python.